# How to control memory usage and time of execution of a thread in .Net/mono?

Tags: multithreading, mono, profiling

I want to provide a way to upload plugins (assemblies) to a site by users for a scripting propose. Through mono.cecil I can analyse those assemblies and limit access only to a predefined list of functions, but I also need to limit memory usage, execution time and kill the thread if it goes to overdraft this resources.

I think I can monitor the memory usage by the profiler api, but as I know there are no tools to abort thread with guarantee. Is there any way to abort thread with guarantee? Maybe I should run code using embedding mono and control the execution of thread in native part of an application, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Thread.Abort() as long as you don't allow the plugin code to ResetAbort().

Comment: It isn't a solution, because if a thread is stuck at finally block, the thread can't be aborted even if it doesn't use ResetAbort().

Answer (score 0):

Thread level control was not practical IMHO (anyone did that in the past). Typically you should consider process level control of memory usage or application domain level.

Comment: Thank, but according to msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unload.aspx) when I call AppDomain.Unload, it tries to abort domain's threads and if this try fails the domain won't be unloaded.

Comment: Then process level control seems the only viable option. No wonder why IE/Chrome use this approach to avoid web page hang.